# Версия JDK для Android-разработки и актуальные уровни API

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я новичок, поэтому прошу сразу тапками не закидывать, а объяснить для чайника или дать ссылки на источники получения исчерпывающей информации :) Сам гуглил долго и упорно, но внятных ответов не нашёл, как мне кажется, по причине недостаточной вовлеченности в эту тему и, как следствие, неспособности составить корректный запрос.

Cобственно вопросы:

1. Какие версии Java поддерживаются различными уровнями Android API?
2. Какую версию JDK устанавливать и использовать для разработки под Android новичку в 2020-2021? В частности, можно ли просто установить последнюю версию, или нужно конкретно ту, возможности которой поддерживаются и используются на максимальных API или же API, используемом в конкретном проекте? (Что скажете насчет Liberica JDK от Bellsoft?)
3. Какой самый низкий уровень API имеет смысл изучать, иначе какие уровни API актуальны на данный момент?

Answer (score 1):

1. По умолчанию вы пишете на Java 7, после определенных действий можно использовать 8. Если вдруг вам 8 потребуется для работы некоторых библиотек вы достаточно быстро это нагуглите, как и действия для перехода на 8
2. По факту можно и не устанавливать первое время, если вы самоучка. Андроид студия несет в себе 8, кажется, версию, и использует ее по умолчанию. Если вы используете сложные скрипты для сборки проекта может потребоваться поставить отдельно или ткнуть через переменные окружения в студийную, но это вам вряд ли потребуется в первые пару лет работы
3. Тут все довольно не однозначно. Для старта я бы порекомендовал 21, это андроид 5.0. Там было внесено куча полезного и упрощающего жизнь, и покрытие 94% устройств, более чем достаточно для начала. Если делаете некоммерческий проект можно и повыше брать, если вдруг когдаа-нибудь придется опустится на версию на которой что-то не сможете сделать, то без особого труда найдете решение как сделать это на более старо SDK. Более серьезные проекты поддерживают с 19го(4.4) или даже 16(4.1). Ниже видел только в давно неподдерживаемых либах. Даже студия не дает при создании проекта выбрать ниже 16. На всякий напомню, что минимальная версия только в файлах настроек упоминаются, скачивать в SDK Manager почти всегда надо последнюю версии

Answer (score 0):

Если вы новичок, то данные вопросы должны вас интересовать меньше всего :).
Устанавливайте `Android Studio` c `Java SE 8` или `Java SE 11` и работайте.

В идеале нужно изучить начиная с версии 1.0, но с практической точки зрения можно остановиться на 14-16 или выше, например с 28, это ваш обдуманный выбор.